# python - password must contain at least one upper or lower case and a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

as a school work, I am trying to make a password encryption/decryption program.
I need consider the following rules:

1. Ensure that every password contains at least one letter (A-Z) or (a-z), one nonalphabetic character (from #, @, %), and at least one digit. The program must reject passwords that violate this rule.
2. Restrict the characters that are allowed in a password to letters (A-Z) and (a-z), digits (0-9) and the three characters (#, @, %). The program must reject passwords that violate this rule.

If the password violates those conditions, I will terminate the program with:

```
print('Invalid password!')
sys.exit()
```

I've been stuck for hours trying to add these conditions... I don't get where to add these conditions, wherever I add them, my program just terminates even though I've input a valid password T-T

Here is what I have so far (I've removed the part for decryption so that I can try to figure out that part for myself afterwards):

```
# import sys module for termination
import sys

# init
password_out = ''
case_changer = ord('a') - ord('A')
encryption_key = (('a','m'), ('b','h'), ('c','t'), ('d','f'), ('e','g'),
  ('f','k'), ('g','b'), ('h','p'), ('i','j'), ('j','w'), ('k','e'),('l','r'),
  ('m','q'), ('n','s'), ('o','l'), ('p','n'), ('q','i'), ('r','u'), ('s','o'),
  ('t','x'), ('u','z'), ('v','y'), ('w','v'), ('x','d'), ('y','c'), ('z','a'),
  ('#', '!'), ('@', '('), ('%', ')'), ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'),
  ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9'))

encrypting = True

# get password
password_in = input('Enter password: ')

# perform encryption / decryption
if encrypting:
    from_index = 0
    to_index = 1
else:
    from_index = 1 
    to_index = 0

case_changer = ord('a') - ord('A')

for ch in password_in:
    letter_found = False

    for t in encryption_key:
        if ('a' <= ch and ch <= 'z') and ch == t[from_index]:  
            password_out = password_out + t[to_index]
            letter_found = True
        elif ('A' <= ch and ch <= 'Z') and chr(ord(ch) + 32) == t[from_index]:
            password_out = password_out + chr(ord(t[to_index]) - case_changer)
            letter_found = True
        elif (ch == '#' or ch == '@' or ch == '%') and ch == t[from_index]:
            password_out = password_out + t[to_index]
        elif (ch >= '0' and ch <= '9') and ch == t[from_index]:
            password_out = password_out + ch

# output
if encrypting:
    print('Your encrypted password is:', password_out)
else:
    print('Your decrypted password is:', password_out)
```

Comment: Word of advice, never write your own encryption. It will not be secure. In addition, password should never be _encrypted_, they should only be salted and hashed.

Comment: thanks, although this is just a coding exercise and the encryption part of the program was given, and just got into defining functions so I am not aware of 'salted' or 'hashed'...

Comment: @MattClark this is a school exercise, not a real application.

Comment: What's with the close vote? Question has specs, problem statement and own code. Not bad for the first one.

Comment: You set a flag `letter_found = True`  but you don't yet have any corresponding flags to note whether a digit has been found or whether a symbol has been found.  Put those in the obvious places (analogous to where you've put the `letter_found` line). Also, it's all very well to *set* these flags, but you need some code that then looks at them (once the looping through the password is done) to see whether they're acceptable (and of course, if they're not acceptable, i.e. not all `True`, then issue the error).

Comment: @timgeb I've encountered several questions closed recently that were actually quite well written and thought out. I'm very frustrated with the elitism of the community lately

Comment: Well you *could* ask this question better by getting rid of everything and asking how to check the given constraints for any string, with a few lines of what has been tried. Anyway, the current state is still not closeworthy imo.

Comment: thank you everyone so much for all the suggestions and help, seems I still havent grasped the idea of functions and def yet, need to go look more into those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regular expressions required

```
import string
import sys

NON_ALPHABETIC_CHARACTERS = {'#', '@', '%'}
DIGITS_CHARACTERS = set(string.digits)
LETTERS_CHARACTERS = set(string.ascii_letters)


def validate_password_1(password,
                        non_alphabetic_characters=NON_ALPHABETIC_CHARACTERS,
                        digits_characters=DIGITS_CHARACTERS,
                        letters_characters=LETTERS_CHARACTERS):
    if not any(character in password
               for character in non_alphabetic_characters):
        err_msg = ('Password should contain at least '
                   'one non-alphabetic character.')
        print(err_msg)
        print('Invalid password!')
        sys.exit()

    if not any(character in password
               for character in digits_characters):
        err_msg = ('Password should contain at least '
                   'one digit character.')
        print(err_msg)
        print('Invalid password!')
        sys.exit()

    if not any(character in password
               for character in letters_characters):
        err_msg = ('Password should contain at least '
                   'one letter character.')
        print(err_msg)
        print('Invalid password!')
        sys.exit()


ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = (NON_ALPHABETIC_CHARACTERS
                      | DIGITS_CHARACTERS
                      | LETTERS_CHARACTERS)


def validate_password_2(password,
                        allowed_characters=ALLOWED_CHARACTERS):
    if not all(character in allowed_characters
               for character in password):
        print('Invalid password!')
        sys.exit()
```

Added additional messages to see what exactly is wrong with given password

Comment: altered some codes here and there, removed some parts where i kept getting errors and finally got my code to work how it should! thank you so much @AzatIbrakov !

Answer (score 1):

This certainly won't qualify as answer for your homework, but you can test that kind of conditions easily with `sets`:

```
import string
alpha = set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)
digits = set(string.digits)
non_alpha = set('#@%')

def is_valid(password):
    password_chars = set(password)

    # We substract the set of letters (resp. digits, non_alpha)
    # from the set of chars used in password
    # If any of the letters is used in password, this should be
    # smaller than the original set 
    all_classes_used = all([len(password_chars - char_class) != len(password_chars) 
                            for char_class in [alpha, digits, non_alpha] ])

    # We remove all letters, digits and non_alpha from the
    # set of chars composing the password, nothing should be left.
    all_chars_valid = len(password_chars - alpha - digits - non_alpha) == 0

    return all_classes_used and all_chars_valid

for pw in ['a', 'a2', 'a2%', 'a2%!']:
    print(pw, is_valid(pw))

# a False
# a2 False
# a2% True
# a2%! False
```

Comment: thank you so much for introducing me into this new world of sets... O_O

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to check for both cases would be to do the following:

```
if password == password.lower() or password == password.upper():
    # Reject password here.
```

We're not going to write the rest of the encryption for you, though!

Comment: @Aaron My bad, forgot that `is` compares identity and not equality.  Thanks!

Comment: What about the number?

Comment: I'm more active in the `Java` section where it's the opposite

Comment: Works (a little too loosely, but never mind) if you want the rule "must contain a digit OR a symbol". But it is under-specified for the rule in the question, i.e. "must contain a digit AND a symbol".

Comment: @jez This answer was just to help OP with the title of the question.  I'm not experienced enough in Python to know if some sort of regular expression system exists.

Comment: In the spirit of this being a homework assignment, I see it a perfectly fine to show how to approach part of the problem, but not completely solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like that using regexp:

```
import re

def test(x):
    regexp = r'[@#%]+[0-9]+@*[a-zA-Z]+'
    sorted_x = ''.join(sorted(x))
    if '@' in sorted_x:
        sorted_x = '@%s' % sorted_x
    p = re.compile(regexp)
    return p.match(sorted_x) is not None
```

Then the function gives :

```
In [34]: test("dfj")
Out[34]: False

In [35]: test("dfj23")
Out[35]: False

In [36]: test("dfj23#")
Out[36]: True
```

If you need one upper AND one lower case letter you can change the regexp to:

```
regexp = r'[@#%]+[0-9]+@*[A-Z]+[a-z]+'
```

The sorted function will put the `#` and the `%` first, then the numbers, then the `@` and finally the letters (first the uper case and then the lower case). Because the `@` is put in the middle, I put one first if I find one in the string.

So at the end you want a string with at least a special character : `[@#%]+`, at least a number `[0-9]+`, optionally there can be a `@` in the middle, and finally a letter `[a-zA-Z]+` (or if you want upper and lower `[A-Z]+[a-z]+`).

Comment: your second test case doesn't include a special character.

Comment: In light of the op being apparently new to python, an explanation of what your match pattern is doing would be appropriate

Comment: Also doesn't it need to have both an uppercase and lowercase letter?

Comment: `at least one letter (A-Z) or (a-z)`. @MooingRawr You're right. I've updated the regexp.

Comment: i do not understand this regexp... but thank you for the suggestion!